# Replacing the places of the values using split and replace method

Tags: java, string, methods, split, output

This is my method, which return List of String value like this: `10x2021`

And this is the value that I have sent to my method.

```
 List<HistoryItem> historyItems = Arrays.asList
                (
                        new HistoryItem(364, "10x2021", Long.valueOf("009"))

                );



public static List<String> foo(List<HistoryItem> historyItems) {
    List<HistoryItem> collect = historyItems.stream().filter(item -> item.getCreditStatus().equals(Long.valueOf("009")) || item.getCreditStatus().equals(Long.valueOf("0010")))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<String> reportingPeriods = new ArrayList<>();
    for (HistoryItem historyItem : historyItems) {
        reportingPeriods.add(historyItem.getReportingPeriod());
    }

    return reportingPeriods;
}
```

What I want to do is I want the output to look like `2021-10 , 2021-9, not 10x2021` . I could not use the methods of the string, exactly as I wanted. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you reduce this down to the specific problem. Are you trying to turn `10x2021` into `2021-10` ? That could be done with a regular expression or a String.split

Comment: yes it is. I want to turn it and put a comma at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix it for you:

```
List<String> reportingPeriods = historyItems.stream().map(hI -> { 
String[] splitted = hI.getReportingPeriod().split("x");
return splitted [1] + "-" + splitted [0]; }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: We forgot something, can you tell us how to put a comma at the end? @Ali Ben Zarrouk

Comment: You mean having something like 2021-9, 2021-9, 2021-9 ?

Comment: Yes I do. 2021-10 , 2021-9, 2021-8 like this.

Comment: you can do String.join(",", reportingPeriods) or instead of collecting to list collecting to joined string immediately with .collect(Collectors.joining(","))

Comment: why did we use map method instead of filter? As far as I know, we have not done any translation here.

Comment: I just added in this line splitted[0] + ","; and worked, but Let's say I don't want a comma when it reaches the last item, how can I do that?

Comment: Thats why I said use, String.join(",", reportingPeriods) or .collect(Collectors.joining(",")). And the map is because you are transferring historyItem object to a string of format year-month. map is used for "mapping" one type to another.

Comment: String commaSeparatedPeriods = historyItems.stream().map(hI -> { 
String[] splitted = hI.getReportingPeriod().split("x");
return splitted [1] + "-" + splitted [0]; }).collect(Collectors.joining(","));

Comment: I understand, but the method needs to return a list.

Comment: Then do on that returned list ```String.join(",", reportingPeriods)```

Comment: can you do what you want to say by renewing your comment in the code?